# Avoiding trigering foreign key constraint when dropdown is not selected

Tags: forms, laravel, input, laravel-5

I have a select dropdown using laravel form helper like so:

```
{!! Form::label('job_id', 'Job Titlle', ['class' => ' control-label']) !!}
{!! Form::select('job_id', $jobs, null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Select']) !!}
```

The problem is this causes a foreign key constraint when I try to update the model
           . I think an empty string is passed and I don't lnow how to stop that from happening.

please help Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did the trick for me.

```
if(isset($request['fk_id']) && empty($request['fk_id'])) {
            $request['fk_id'] = null;
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

1) [Validate](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation) the data before sending it off to the database; something like this in your controller will do the trick:

```
class JobController extends Controller
{
    public function store(Request $request)
    {

        $this->validate($request, [
             'job_id' => 'required'
        ]);

        // Store in the database because data is valid
    }
}
```

2) If job_id is not really required, you can avoid the foreign key contraint failure by specifying the column as `nullable`

Answer (score 1):

In Database table make column `null`

```
ALTER mytable MODIFY mycolumn varchar(255) null;
```